# When self-hosting ASP.NET Core - does it use http.sys if available?

Tags: asp.net-core, http.sys

`http.sys` is a kernel-mode driver present in Windows that greatly speeds-up the processing and routing of incoming HTTP requests. It was added during the days of Windows NT 4 to give the then-nascant IIS a benchmark boost compared to Apache.

For those unfamiliar: it's a component that hijacks incoming HTTP requests (on port 80 and 443, you can configure it to monitor other ports too) and routes them to different userland applications based on its configuration, see MSDN for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364510(v=vs.85).aspx

Today, provided you use IIS to host your application, you'll be taking advantage of `http.sys`.

However, I can't find any information that states whether or not self-hosted ASP.NET Core applications will be using `http.sys` if present.

Comment: I found this page of [Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS).
**And he says:**
First and foremost, if you want to have multiple applications running on a single server that all share port 80 and port 443 you can't run Kestrel directly. Kestrel doesn't support host header routing which is required to allow multiple port 80 bindings on a single IP address. Without IIS (or http.sys actually) you currently can't do this using Kestrel alone (and I think this is not planned either).

It looks like, that it doesn't...

Comment: So if it would use http.sys under the hood, it would also support host header routing, that's what i understood, perhaps i am wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Kestrel doesn't use or support http.sys (it must also run on Linux which doesn't have http.sys), you can use [WebListener](https://github.com/aspnet/WebListener) (also [here](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/weblistener), which uses http.sys and usage example [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/204)) to achieve this. However, only on Windows for obvious reasons.

Unlike Kestrel, WebListener is considered production ready, which means you can use it to host internet facing applications. Kestrel on other side isn't there yet, so the official recommendation at the time of the wrtiting is to always use Kestrel behind a reverse proxy (IIS, nginx etc.).